# Does huge database table affect the speed of the page load?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Does huge database table effect the speed of the page load ?

**for example :** If i have database with table name "Images" and this table have 3 columns: ID , Name and src
now if i have 100 image info in that table and I use php to select from the database and order by ID

Will it take the same time to do so  as it would take for 1,000,000 Image info ?

if it does effect ... how long time it need to sort 1 million Image info ?

I tried to see the difference between 100 image and 1000 but it was the same .. but i am afraid if it become big it slow down the website ..

i am using this code to get results from database :

```
SELECT * FROM 4images_images ORDER BY image_id DESC
```

Comment: It depends on several factors.

Comment: There are many factors that may affect performance. Don't optimise too early. Wait until you see a problem and address it then.

Comment: like what factors ..

Comment: @HoboSapiens it would be hard to manage once the database is really big

Comment: 1 million rows is not that big for mysql. Keep in mind you can do other things to cache the output of any page. Just because the site is dynamic doesn't mean it has to read from the DB to load the site. Look at facebook. They serve mostly or entirely static pages.

Comment: @KaiQing I am using in php .. select from table_images ORDER by ID; 
is this the right way to call from database or is there any faster way

Comment: that would work. Make sure you put a limit on it. A faster way would be to cache the results and only perform the read when necessary. Pull the images, write the html to a flat text file, serve that file on load and only rewrite the html when the table changes. That's just the beginning but it is enough of an idea to get you started.

Comment: table will be changing always coz ppl will upload images , anyway thank you for your help ill read more about that , i am new in here tho .. thanks..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do you mean 'page' web page?  A large database could effect how fast a query completes which can delay a page.

Queries can be optimized. Tables can be optimized. This allows a query to complete quickier.  Therefore it is not  true statement to say a large database can cause a page to load slowly.  However, it is a likely cause.

Comment: so huge database and small database would preform the same ?

Comment: Careful.  I said a large database/table can perform quickly and a small database/table can perform slowly.  There are several factors to impact the performance of a database.  Indexing, data typing, data conversions, collation, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The size of the database table will probably only matter if your query forces it to look through a lot of rows. Practice 3rd Normal Form.